# Cant install Pyhash package on Mac OS 12.3.1 Monterey

Tags: python-3.x

I get this error when I run 'pip3 install pyhash'

```
        return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                        ^                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
      fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      20 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pyhash
```

What can I do to fix this. I have spent many hours trying to figure this out and it always leads me to this same error.

Comment: After more research I found that this has something to do with my Arm chip. When the code is being compiled it tried to use an AMD architecture which I do not have. I tried to pip3 install pyhash with Rosetta and I get the same error. Gotta love the M1 Macs....